# Parse input string

Tags: php, string, parsing

I have a strings like this:

```
index.php?url=index/index
index.php?url=index/index/2&a=b
```

I'm trying to get this part of string: `index/index` or `index/index/2.`

I have tried parse_str function but not successful.
Thanks.

Comment: Show your current code example.

Comment: `/` needs to be urlencoded for the `parse_str` to work.

Comment: echo '<pre>';
  parse_str($filename, $output);
  print_r($output);
  echo '<pre>';

Comment: `$filename` is not defined in your comment. Edit your post and put a [mcve] into it.

Comment: You can use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to extract the query string and then [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get at the arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] as shown below:

```
$url_params = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; // grabs the parameter
$url_params = explode( '/', $url_params ); // seperates the params by '/'
```

which returns an array

Example index.php?url=index/index2 now becomes:

```
$url_params[ 0 ] =  index;
$url_params[ 1 ] =  index2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more info:

```
// Example input
$input               = "index.php?url=index/index/2&a=b";
$after_question_mark = explode("=",$input)[1];
$before_ampersand    = explode("&",$after_question_mark)[0];
$desired_output      = $before_ampersand; // 'index/index/2'
```

More resilient option:

```
// Example input
$input               = "index.php?url=index/index/2&a=b";
$after_question_mark = explode("=",$input)[1];
if (strstr($after_question_mark, "&")){
    // Check for ampersand
    $before_ampersand    = explode("&",$after_question_mark)[0];
    $desired_output      = $before_ampersand; // 'index/index/2'
} else {
    // No ampersand
    $desire_output       = $after_question_mark;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$url = "index.php?url=index/index/2&a=b";
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$output = substr($query, $strpos($query, "=") + 1);
output: index/index/2&a=b
```

This will get you everything after the question mark

You can get more info on [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

or

```
$url = "index.php?url=index/index/2&a=b";
$output = substr($url, strpos("=") +1, $strrpos($url, "&") - strlen($url));
output: index/index/2
```

You dont need to break into an array to create overhead if you really just want to get a substring from a string

this will return false on no query string

Comment: I have edited my answer to fit your request...but mainly `parse_url` is the function to go for..imho